# How to make a slider where you have to hit the middle of it in order to cause it to go to another scene

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to flash and want to make a slider where something moves back and for until you hit space bar in order to make land in the middle which would trigger a new scene.  Sort of like a mini game.

[image]
Again im really new to actionscript so any help would be nice.  I was thinking of calling like a function where the pointer is continuously moving until the space bar is hit.  But Im really stuck.  Please and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your slider has the instance name "slider". Then try this code:

```
//x position of the most left position of the slider
var left_limit:Number = 50
//x position of the most right position of the slider
var right_limit:Number = 250

var speed:Number = 10
var dir:int = 1

//How close the slider has to be to the middle to trigger the next scene
var tolerance:Number = 10

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop)
addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keydown)

function loop(e:Event){
    slider.x += speed*dir
    if(slider.x>right_limit){
        slider.x = right_limit
        dir = -1
    }else if(slider.x<left_limit){
        slider.x = left_limit
        dir = 1
    }
}
function keydown(e:KeyboardEvent){
    if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop)
        if(Math.abs((slider.x-left_limit)-(right_limit-left_limit)/2)<tolerance){
            //succeeded go to next scene
            gotoAndStop("scene2")
        }else{
            //failed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa you went a way I wasn't even close to thinking of.  Thank you!